# PLI Verilog: how to restart a simulation

Tags: c, verilog

I'd like to restart my simulation using the PLI. I use VCS.

I wrote this :
`vpi_control(vpiReset,1);`

in a callback function catched by the `cbEndOfSimulation`
The simulator gets the reset call but does not use the extra parameter as it's written in the documentation: The simulation is restarted but in interactive mode !
I also tested with 3 parameters ...

Is this the correct way to restart a simulation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing looks correct according to the VPI spec:

```
PLI_INT32 vpi_control(
   PLI_INT32 operation,  /* constant representing the operation to perform */
             ...)        /* variable number of arguments as required by the
                            operation */
```

Where operation vpiReset is equivalent to the `$reset` system task and therefore requires three arguments, `stop_value`, `reset_value` and `diagnostic_level`.

I know this is stating the obvious but are you checking the return value is 1 (indicating success) and not 0 (indicating failure)?

The only other suggestions I can make are:

1. Try calling the equivalent `$reset` system task from Verilog and see if that behaves as expected
2. Try running your test program against a different simulator

If these demonstrate that VCS is deficient then at least you have a good testcase for raising a support ticket and hoping Synopsys will provide you with a patch relatively promptly.

If this is a VCS bug you might be able to work around it by causing `$reset` to be called by Verilog - assuming `$reset` works as intended - or there may be something you could do in a `cbEnterInteractive` callback to take corrective action.

Comment: Based on this answer, I get the feeling that @user1059422 just isn't calling the API correctly. `IEEE Std 1364-2001` describes the `vpiReset` command as `causes the $reset built-in Verilog system task to be executed upon return
of the user function. This operation shall be passed three additional integer
arguments: stop_value, reset_value and diagnostic_level, which are the
same values passed to the $reset system task (see C.7)`  so I would try with all 3 additional integer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately, I already tested the $reset; routine.

When I call it with `$reset;` or `$reset(0);` the simulation is reset in interactive mode.
When I call `$reset(1)` or `$reset(1,0,0)`, the simulation is reset not in interactive mode (as described in the documentation).

For the second suggestion, I don't have access to another simulator...

Comment: [Icarus](http://iverilog.icarus.com/) supports VPI and is free so you could try that.  Since `$reset` works as expected you could also try the suggested workaround of calling back down into Verilog from your C code and calling `$reset` from Verilog?

Comment: Of course, $reset is a possible workaround.
But I'd like my VPI interface the most independant from Verilog code.